# Iterate over potential generators

Tags: python, iterator

I need to iterate over a stream of pandas.Series objects (the kind of objects I want to use us irrelevant though). Optionally, an arbitrary function is applied to each Series, and - here is the clincher - this arbitrary function can be a generator function, that yields two (or more) values. I was hopeful for the `more_itertools.flatten` function, but it doesn't help because it breaks in case a regular function, or no function is mapped over the generator. Is there a way to turn this iterable into a simple generator of Series objects? Here is a simple example that shows the issue:

```py
In [1]: from more_itertools import flatten
   ...: 
   ...: def generator():
   ...:     for i in range(10):
   ...:         yield i
   ...: 
   ...: def postprocess1(i):
   ...:     yield 2*i
   ...: 
   ...: def postprocess1_return(i):
   ...:     return 2*i
   ...: 
   ...: def postprocess2(i):
   ...:     yield from (i, 2*i)
   ...: 

In [2]: list(generator())
   ...: 
Out[2]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

In [3]: list(map(postprocess1, generator()))
   ...: 
Out[3]: 
[<generator object postprocess1 at 0x7f5a402916d0>,
 <generator object postprocess1 at 0x7f5a40291e40>,
 <generator object postprocess1 at 0x7f5a40291f20>,
 <generator object postprocess1 at 0x7f5a40291dd0>,
 <generator object postprocess1 at 0x7f5a40291eb0>,
 <generator object postprocess1 at 0x7f5a40209040>,
 <generator object postprocess1 at 0x7f5a40209190>,
 <generator object postprocess1 at 0x7f5a402092e0>,
 <generator object postprocess1 at 0x7f5a402090b0>,
 <generator object postprocess1 at 0x7f5a40209350>]

In [4]: list(map(postprocess1_return, generator()))
   ...: 
Out[4]: [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]

In [5]: list(map(postprocess2, generator()))
   ...: 
Out[5]: 
[<generator object postprocess2 at 0x7f5a403ad430>,
 <generator object postprocess2 at 0x7f5a40209580>,
 <generator object postprocess2 at 0x7f5a402097b0>,
 <generator object postprocess2 at 0x7f5a40209510>,
 <generator object postprocess2 at 0x7f5a40209430>,
 <generator object postprocess2 at 0x7f5a40209740>,
 <generator object postprocess2 at 0x7f5a402096d0>,
 <generator object postprocess2 at 0x7f5a40209820>,
 <generator object postprocess2 at 0x7f5a40209660>,
 <generator object postprocess2 at 0x7f5a40209890>]

In [6]: list(flatten(generator()))
   ...: 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-7cd770547fa4> in <module>
----> 1 list(flatten(generator()))

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

In [7]: list(flatten(map(postprocess1, generator())))
   ...: 
Out[7]: [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]

In [8]: list(flatten(map(postprocess1_return, generator())))
   ...: 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-35ce9aef7285> in <module>
----> 1 list(flatten(map(postprocess1_return, generator())))

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

In [9]: list(flatten(map(postprocess2, generator())))
Out[9]: [0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 4, 3, 6, 4, 8, 5, 10, 6, 12, 7, 14, 8, 16, 9, 18]
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out: `more_itertools.collapse(generator, base_type=pd.Series)` does the trick!

And clearly the type of the base values is actually important: without the `base_type=pd.Series` in my actual code all elements of a series a yielded one by one, and that's not what I wanted.